# Form Validation: Select

Tags: forms, select, validation

I'm trying to display an error message if the select button in my form is not changed. It works fine for the rest but not the select, please help! and I know that the image wont work like that, I cant post images as a new member.

Html is:

```
<div id='first_name_error' class='error'><image code here></div>
<div><input type='text' name='first_name' id='first_name' placeholder="YOUR FIRST NAME*"></div>

Number of Guests:*<div id='guests_error' class='error'><img src='img/booking/error.png'></div>
<div><select name='guests' id='guests' style="margin:0px;" SIZE="1"><OPTION SELECTED value="guests">Guests<OPTION>2<OPTION>3<OPTION>4</SELECT></div>
```

Code Is

```
        var error = false;  
    var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
var second_name = $('#second_name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
var number = $('#number').val();
var guests = $('#guests').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();

if(first_name.length == 0){var error = true;$('#first_name_error').fadeIn(500);}else{$('#first_name_error').fadeOut(500);}

if(guests.value == Guests){var error = true;$('#guests_error').fadeIn(500);}else{$('#guests_error').fadeOut(500);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that your "guests" variable is already set to the value of the select element (using jQuery val()).  There is no need to attempt to access the "value" property of the "guests" variable.

Second, the comparison you are making is to the identifier `Guests`, not to the string "Guests".  You'll want to put quotes around that to make it a string literal.

You can see an example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/tbuCJ/